# getting rid of the upper or lower triangular part of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a symmetric matrix of some statistical values that I want to plot using imagesc in Matlab. The size of the matrix is 112 X 28, meaning I want to display 4 rows for each column. How can I get rid of the upper or lower triangular part of this matrix ? Since this means deleting 4 rows per each column diagonally tril or triu functions does not work (they are for square matrices).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nice answers but maybe this one can be an alternative using triu function:

```
% image
img = rand(112, 28);

% utilize a square matrix to use triu command
temp = nan(112, 112);
temp(:, 1:4:end) = img;
temp = triu(temp, -3);

% put the relevant elements back
img = temp(:, 1:4:end);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `kron` function

```
kron(triu(ones(28)),[1 ;1 ;1 ;1])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you could use `imresize` to resize an upper triangular mask that you can then use to select the appropriate data

```
msk = imresize(triu(true(min(size(a)))), size(a), 'nearest');

% Just zero-out the lower diag
zeroed = msk .* a;

% Select the elements in the upper diagonal
upperdiag = a(msk);
```

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox (and `imresize`) you can do something like

```
msk = reshape(repmat(permute(triu(true(min(size(a)))), [3 1 2]), size(a,1)/size(a,2), 1), size(a));
```

Comment: Yes I have the Image Processing Toolbox and I got what I want by
imagesc(zeroed)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution using `meshgrid`

First define a grid which covers all the indices of your matrix

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid([1:28], [1:112]);
```

You want to mask all values above (or below) the diagonal 4x = y. Just define the mask to be the function of your X and Y values.

```
mask = 4.*X >= Y; %>= Selects above the diagonal, <= selects below the diagonal
```

Here's the mask. Notice that the axises are not symmetric.

[image: Diagonal Mask]

You can use this method to define any separating line or function on the grid. You could even do a parabola

```
mask_parabola = (X-14).^2 >= Y;
```

[image: Parabola Mask]

Answer (score 2):

You can create the mask with [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
M = 112; % number of rows
N = 28; % number of columns
mask = bsxfun(@le, (1:M).', (1:N)*round(M/N)); % create mask
data = data.*mask; % multiply your data matrix by the mask
```